# Data extraction function not returning what it should

Tags: python

I currently have this piece of code that I am working on that is extracting data from an API, my goal is to create a discord bot that visualizes some of this data, but I have run into a problem. Here we go:

```
import requests
import json
import discord


headers = {
        'accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer apiKEY',
    }

params = (
        ('type', 'ongoing'),
        ('offset', '0'),
        ('limit', '20'),
    )

def liveGames(headers,params):
    hubList = ['bed6a13f-6aa3-4d01-839f-b83a9d26c589', '627e10d3-00ac-4376-9f62-a22812e220b1',
               'e244b64a-2a54-43a2-8a0e-df2380a8c1cc', 'e7ee1bc8-2be1-4512-955e-5542daae4152',
               '73b8f93e-6a49-4abd-90e7-71caa4735c04', '89b35fc4-cc30-4966-842e-9d5d3a47d09c']

    for hub in hubList:
        matchList = []
        requestURL = 'https://open.faceit.com/data/v4/hubs/' + hub + '/matches'
        response = requests.get(requestURL, headers=headers, params=params)
        matchDeets = response.json()
        packageName = "items"
        gameRoom = "match_id"
        players = ""
        matchPackage = json.dumps(matchDeets, indent = 2)
        testVar = True
        COUNTER = 0
        while testVar != False:
            try:
                matchPackage = json.dumps(matchDeets[packageName][COUNTER][gameRoom])
                matchLink = "https://www.faceit.com/en/csgo/room/"+matchPackage
                fixedMatchLink = matchLink.replace('"', '')
                if fixedMatchLink not in matchList :
                    matchList.append(fixedMatchLink)
                COUNTER += 1
            except:
                testVar = False

        print(matchList)
    return matchList

b = liveGames(headers,params)
print(b)
```

My `print` statement prints the correct list with all the URL's, but when I return it and try to print it, it just prints an empty list. How can I fix this? (I removed my API key from the code block.)

Comment: ``matchList = []`` repleaces ``matchList`` with a new, *empty* list on each iteration. The last iteration does likely not produce any matches. Can you please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]? Mock or replace the requests so that the code can be run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `matchList = []` from out of the for loop. When it is in the loop, it will keep redefining itself to an empty list. Alternatively, you can have another variable like `matchLists`, and you can append the value of `matchList` to `matchLists` at the end of the for loop.

Comment: err, no. matchList will only contain its last contents from the last iteration of the for loop. But, yes the solution is to move it up as you say.

Comment: A ``for`` lopp does not have separate scope. ``matchList`` is accessible outside the ``for`` loop if it has run at least once. The problem is likely that ``matchList`` is *replaced* with a new, empty least on each iteration.

Comment: Yes, @MisterMiyagi, I couldn't find a way to phrase it correctly. Every time the for loop runs, `matchList` with reset itself back to an empty list. This is why I wanted you to move it out of the loop.